# Method must have a return type (Unity 3D)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make my player have a constant speed forwards and i get this error when compiling.

```
public class Speed
{
    public static int movespeed = 1;
    public Vector3 userDirection = Vector3.right;
    public Start()
    {

    }

    public void Update()
    {
        transform.Translate(userDirection * movespeed * Time.deltaTime); 
    }
}
```

Comment: public void Start

Comment: What is `Start()` method? Is it supposed to be constructor, if yes, please change it to `public Speed()` else provide a return type for that method.

Comment: [Coding in Unity for the Absolute Beginner](https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/coding-unity-absolute-beginner)

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the return type of Start method :

public **void** Start()

By the way you also forgot inheritence to MonoBehavior (if you want to attach your script to a game object) ;-)

public class Speed : **MonoBehaviour**

```
public class Speed : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static int movespeed = 1;
    public Vector3 userDirection = Vector3.right;

    public void Start()
    {
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        transform.Translate(userDirection * movespeed * Time.deltaTime); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your start method doesn't have a return type. Assign it one instead.

```
public void Start()
{
}
```

By the way this is really basic and shouldn't belong here.